# jQuery first child of "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I'm trying to pass "this" from a clicked span to a jQuery function that can then execute jQuery on that clicked element's first child. Can't seem to get it right...

```
<p onclick="toggleSection($(this));"><span class="redClass"></span></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggleSection(element) {
  element.toggleClass("redClass");
}
```

How do I reference the :first-child of element?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why don't you bind event handlers using jQuery also?

Comment: because bind event handlers have to be initialized in document.ready() which adds a performance hit (this is an app for IE6). or is there another way?

Comment: Hm.. not sure. Binding using jQuery is the standard way (if you're already using jQuery). What kind of performance hit are you experiencing when you use `jQuery(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: It's a large application with 7+ developers. It was originally 4+ seconds before I tried to clean it up a bit. So I'd rather avoid adding more to it when I don't have to  :)

Answer (score 535, accepted):

If you want to apply a selector to the context provided by an existing jQuery set, try the [find() function](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
element.find(">:first-child").toggleClass("redClass");
```

Jørn Schou-Rode noted that you probably only want to find the first *direct descendant* of the context element, hence [the child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) (>). [He also points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275702/jquery-first-child-of-this/2275728#2275728) that you could just as well use the [children() function](http://api.jquery.com/children), which is very similar to find() but only searches one level deep in the hierarchy (which is all you need...):

```
element.children(":first").toggleClass("redClass");
```

Comment: thanks! works perfectly. I imagine the other ways listed below will work as well.

Comment: I believe `find()` searches through all descendants, and `:first-child` can match one element per parent. Hence, this query can is likely to return several elements. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Jørn: you're correct, I hadn't thought about this - if there is a hierarchy, then an unqualified :first-child selector will produce multiple results.

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer, but the useage of the ">" selector without a parent in that selector is depreciated (for example, ">:firstchild") as of jQuery 1.8. I suggest instead using `element.children(":first-child")` or `element.children().first();`

Comment: @KevinB apparently they decided not to deprecate it after all

Comment: the best approach would be NOT to iterate on all items and then pick the first one, as some suggested here. This would be BAD.

Answer (score 89):

Use the [`children` function](http://api.jquery.com/children/) with the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to get the *single* first child of `element`:

```
element.children(":first").toggleClass("redClass");
```

Comment: element.children()[0].toggleClass("redClass");

Comment: @Zakos: `TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'toggleClass'`

Answer (score 61):

I've added [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-child-fetch) test to see the speed difference for different approaches to get the first child (total 1000+ children)

given, `notif = $('#foo')`

*jQuery ways:*

1. `$(":first-child", notif)` - 4,304 ops/sec - fastest
2. `notif.children(":first")` - 653 ops/sec - 85% slower
3. `notif.children()[0]` - 1,416 ops/sec - 67% slower

*Native ways:*

4. JavaScript native' `ele.firstChild` - **4,934,323** ops/sec (all the above approaches are 100% slower compared to `firstChild`)
5. Native DOM ele from jQery: `notif[0].firstChild` - **4,913,658** ops/sec

So, first 3 jQuery approaches are not recommended, at least for first-child (I doubt that would be the case with many other too). If you have a jQuery object and need to get the first-child, then **get the native DOM element** from the jQuery object, using array reference `[0]` *(recommended)* or `.get(0)` and use the `ele.firstChild`. This gives the same identical results as regular JavaScript usage.

*all tests are done in Chrome Canary build v15.0.854.0*

Comment: Actually, `firstChild` won't give the same results as jQuery's `children()` or selector queries. `firstChild` will include text nodes which is rarely desired. jQuery's `contents()` function *will*  include them, but `children()` won't.  Newer browsers support `firstElementChild` which will give the first child element, but IE < 9 does not support it.  So, if you use `firstChild` you have to manually find the first non-text node child.

Comment: `$(":first-child", notif)` should be `$(":first", notif)` for expected behaviour. The former will return all first-child element descendants.

Comment: When there are no textnodes as direct children! You can choose to use `$(notif[0].firstChild)` for performance reasons when many children are involved. Then you end with a jQuery object again. On a JSBench.me I got 8,728 ops/s with `notif.children(":first")` and a whopping **12,440,220** ops/s  for `$(notif[0].firstChild)`. I used 1000 child nodes to test with.

Answer (score 32):

```
element.children().first();
```

Find all children and get first of them.

Comment: By far the simplest method, and more efficient than `.children(':first')`.

Comment: How is it more efficient? It seems that it gets all children, then takes the first one, versus getting just the first child.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757072/940098

Answer (score 13):

you can use DOM

```
$(this).children().first()
// is equivalent to
$(this.firstChild)
```

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried

```
$(":first-child", element).toggleClass("redClass");
```

I think you want to set your element as a context for your search. There might be a better way to do this which some other jQuery guru will hop in here and throw out at you :)

Comment: this will fail if `element` has grand-children

Answer (score 5):

I've just written a plugin which uses `.firstElementChild` if possible, and falls back to iterating over each individual node if necessary:

```
(function ($) {
    var useElementChild = ('firstElementChild' in document.createElement('div'));

    $.fn.firstChild = function () {
        return this.map(function() {
            if (useElementChild) {
                return this.firstElementChild;
            } else {
                var node = this.firstChild;
                while (node) {
                    if (node.type === 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    node = node.nextSibling;
                }
                return node;
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It's not as fast as a pure DOM solution, but in [jsperf tests](http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-child-fetch/6) under Chrome 24 it was a couple of orders of magnitude faster than any other jQuery selector-based method.

Comment: I like this plugin - but there are 2 issues: 1) The plugin script cannot be included in the head because `document.body` is not initialized yet, 2) The performance is only much better than alternatives if the number of child nodes is very high. For only a few children (say less than 10) the `$('>:first-child',context)` is a little bit faster. Only the number of children affects the performance, not the depth.

Comment: @codefactor good point about `document.body` - I'll look into that.

Answer (score 4):

please use it like this
first thing give a class name to tag p like "myp"

then on use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myp").click(function() {
        $(this).children(":first").toggleClass("classname"); // this will access the span.
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a simple magic like this:

```
$(":first-child", element).toggleClass("redClass");
```

Reference: http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-first-child-selector

Answer (score -2):

i am using

```
 $('.txt').first().css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: This is plain wrong? Apart from no definition of class `txt` in the script, `first()` wouldn't do the job: "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set." [link](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score -5):

If you want immediate first child you need

```
    $(element).first();
```

If you want particular first element in the dom from your element then use below

```
    var spanElement = $(elementId).find(".redClass :first");
    $(spanElement).addClass("yourClassHere");
```

try out : http://jsfiddle.net/vgGbc/2/

Comment: this is just wrong - if `element` is a DOM node then `$(element).first()` is equivalent to `$(element)`, not its first child.

Comment: Agreed, if element is a DOM node $(element).first() is equivalent $(element) this caused me problem with knockoutJS binding