# Make .appendTo() apply to First Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendto

I have this code:

```
<ul id="hello">
    <li>.....</li>
    <li>.....</li>
    <li>.....</li>
    <li>.....</li>
    <li>.....</li>
    <li>.....</li>
</ul>
```

and this Script:

```
$("<label>The First item</label>").appendTo($('ul#hello li'));
```

How can I make it so that the .appendTo() function only applies to the first list item.

I've tried the `:first-child selector` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("<label>The First item</label>").appendTo($('#hello li:first'));
```

Comment: +1, also because passing the element name if you know the ID is useless.

Comment: @pimvdb: Not always. You could use the same ID on a different element on a different page. In that case `ul#hello` won't match `div#hello`. I admit, in practice this doesn't happen a lot.

Comment: @Geert: You shouldn't have 2 elements with the same ID, that defeats the whole purpose of IDs.

Comment: @Rocket: I said: "same ID on a different element *on a different page*". That's perfectly valid and possible.

Comment: @Greet: Yes you did, sorry, I need more caffeine.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("<label>The First item</label>").appendTo($('#hello li').first());
```

Note: `.first()` should be a tad faster than `:first`.
Also see: [jQuery :first vs. .first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312761/jquery-first-vs-first)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#hello li:first').append('<label>The First item</label>');
```

or

```
$('#hello').find('li:first').append('<label>The First item</label>');
```

or

```
$('<label>The First item</label>').appendTo($('#hello').find('li:first'));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8NJM/1/)**