# jquery addClass not working: "property or method addClass not supported"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, addclass

I got this javascript working

```
$(".mail-tile").click(function () {
    var idMessage = $(this).attr('data-message-id');
    $('.mail-tile').removeClass(classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata);
    $(this).addClass(classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata);
    previewMail(this);        
});
```

then, in the same page, same js file, I've got this javascript:

```
function selectMail(idMail) {
    var mailTile = $('.mail-tile[data-message-id="' + idMail + '"]')[0];    
    $('.mail-tile').removeClass(classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata);
    mailTile.addClass(classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata);
    previewMail(mailTile);
}
```

In this case, the addClass function doesn't work: "property or method addClass not supported".

`classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata` is a global variable.

I can't understand what's the difference between the two snippet. In both case I got an HtmlDivElement to work with (the object is not null).
What's going on here?

Comment: You're missing the quotes before and after the classnames:

Comment: your are missing semicolon after `mailTile.addClass(classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata)`

Comment: @kayen: nope, `classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata` is a global string variable which contains the actual name of the class. Thanks for poiting out. Question updated to be more precise

Comment: @Elen: missing semicolon whas just a copy/paste mistake. That's not the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the **[0]** after your ID selector. That would not give you the `jQuery element` to which you're using `addClass(classeEvidenzaRigaSelezionata)` later.

Use this instead: `var mailTile = $('.mail-tile[data-message-id="' + idMail + '"]');`

Comment: You are right. But it doesn't return an array of element in this case?

Comment: Yes it does, so if you need to access the first element, you'll need to do something like: 

var mailTile = $('.mail-tile[data-message-id="' + idMail + '"]:first');

Comment: @kayen or better yet `.first()`, although if the array is guaranteed to only have one element there's no need.

Comment: @Alnitak - Yes, .first() is an alternative but in this case you're constructing a new jQuery object. Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312761/jquery-first-vs-first

Comment: @kayen yes, but creating a new jQuery object is faster than using the non-standard `:first` selector which prevents use of the browser's native `querySelectorAll()` function.  See http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for the info! So I guess, we can combine our two cases and come up with the fastest and optimal selector using .filter(":first").

Someone actually did a test on these: http://jsperf.com/first-v-first/2

Comment: @kayen no, since `.filter(':first')` is still slower than `.first()` - the former requires parsing the selector, whereas the latter just requires a trivial array operation.

Comment: @Alnitak - Thanks for creating the test! .first() is fast indeed!