# ( "p:first" ) vs ("p").first() Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small script.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $( "p" ).first().replaceWith("Hello world!");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Replace the first p element with new text</button>
```

This replaces the content inside the first

with "Hello world!".

I got same result with 2 jquery script.

```
1) ( "p:first" )
2) ("p").first()
```

What is the exact difference between these 2 scripts.

Comment: No difference, just different ways of getting to the same thing. I can also use `$('p').eq(0)`. That is why jQuery is so awesome: millions of ways to get the same result! However, some selectors may affect performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally, they are equivalent. However, in terms of performance, `p:first` will be better. This is because `p:first` begins to scan the DOM and stops at the first `p` element it finds. `$('p').first()` on the other hand, has to scan the entire DOM and generate an array of all `p` elements, and then pick the first element from that array.

This performance difference, however, will be negligible unless you have a very large DOM.

**EDIT**

Interestingly, [`:first` isn't faster than `.first()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757072/315828). Hmm, not sure I understand why, but it's been benchmarked.

Comment: Well said and I am glad you pointed out `will be negligible unless you have a very large DOM.`. The more elements in the DOM, the more elements to scan, which will ultimately impact performance.

Comment: :first is a pseudo class. It does not benefit from the speed benefits of typical CSS-standard selectors.

Comment: @jyarbro - I guess that's true. I'd have imagined jQuery would be optimized to end the DOM traversal after it found the first `p`, but it seems not.

Comment: I suppose `.first()` is faster because of delegating selector to `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: `p:first` does **not** stop at the first `p`. It reads all `p` elements and returns the first one. Sizzle has no shortcut for `:first`.

Answer (score 2):

According to performance test [found here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-vs-first-selector) the second way (`$("p").first();`) is much faster.

Comment: Even the jQuery docs mention the performance implications of `:first`. So why exactly do you think it performs better?

Comment: Because it's compared to selecting a full set of paragraphs and then picking the first one. At least that's how chained methods should work.

Comment: Both solutions essentially get all paragraphs and then pick the first one. The difference is that the `p:first` only returns the first paragraph in the first place. But `:first` can be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: You're right. According to test performed here http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-vs-first-selector the second one might be much faster. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) is a selector that should be used when performance is less important than readable code. It is not a CSS-standard selector, and therefore does not benefit from the speed of built-in browser performance enhancements. When using a significant number of OTHER selectors though, it will help make your code easier to process mentally since you're executing similar code in similar ways.

The best performance for `:first` is to execute your initial query (`$("p")`), then execute a `.filter(":first")`. This negates my readable code statement though, as you're now doing something syntactically different from other selectors.

.first() is syntactic sugar for .eq(0), which does the exact same thing, but is significantly less readable.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any real difference, but the best way to find out is to benchmark it for example [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-benchmark). The benchmarking has been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757072/2610249) (`.first()` wins).

Answer (score 0):

The first one requires the pseudo-selector to be parsed and then executed and. It would return only one paragraph on the initial invocation. The second one executes a selector on all paragraphs and then returns the first one in the second jQuery call with `first()`.

My suggestion is to check the jQuery source in order to verify for yourself what the implementation difference is.

Answer (score 0):

First on `:filter` is slower as it includes sizzler library. which needs to do extra work.

[Here is a test to run and see performance](http://jsperf.com/eq-vs-eq)