# Selecting a table row with a particular class using first-child

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I've found an odd bug where the CSS `:first-child` selector doesn't seem to be able to select a table row for me.

I have the following table

```
<table>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="b">
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="b">
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c">
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c">
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add a row before the first instance of tr.b.

This code will not work:

```
$("table tr.b:first-child").before("<tr><td>using css selector</td></tr>");
```

but this will work fine:

```
$("table tr.b").first().before("<tr><td>using jquery first()</td></tr>");
```

Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong? I don't mind using jQuery but I don't understand why this isn't working with pure CSS.

Here's a fiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/5d6YX/

Comment: it is how :first-child is support to work... it does not look for the first element matching a criteria... it always represents the first child of a parent element... in your case the `.b` element is not the first child of the parent `.a` is so `.b:fist-child` won't return anything

Comment: Are you looking for `$("table tr.b:first")`?

Comment: your css selector  `table tr.b:first-child`  check if `tr:first-child` has claas `.b` . in your code the first `tr` child of table has class `.a`.  the second tr is `nth-child(2)` .:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery :first vs. .first()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312761/jquery-first-vs-first)

Comment: @Mr_Green: But this question is about `:first-child`, not `:first`.

Comment: @BoltClock oops yep.. sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how it suppose to work.The `:first` pseudo-class is equivalent to `:eq(0)`. It could also be written as `:lt(1)`. While this matches only a single element, `:first-child` can match more than one: One for each parent.

Try this:

```
$("table tr.b:first").before("<tr><td>css selector</td></tr>");
```

OR

```
$("table tr.b:eq(0)").before("<tr><td>css selector</td></tr>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5d6YX/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just about CSS sibbling with selector.

In CSS , your selecteur would be :

```
table tr:first-child + tr.b
```

to only select the seconf row if it has class `.b`

to select the first .b class , you would need to overwrite the rule.

```
tr.b {/*set my rule */
tr.b ~tr.b {/*reset my rule */
```

It would be nice to have  this kind of CSS selector avalaible : `:first-of-class('myclass');`

Comment: In Selectors 4 that would be `:nth-match(1 of .myclass)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("table tr.b:first").before("<tr><td>css selector</td></tr>");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5d6YX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`$("table tr.b:first")` will do the trick.