# How can I use JQuery to select the first div element inside a container element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I am pretty new in JQuery and I have the following situation:

```
<!-- Bottone relativo ai progetti WIFI: -->
<a title="WIFI" href="javascript: void(0)" id="showWifi_${item.index}" class="showWifi">
    <div class="news_box news_box_01 hvr-underline-from-center " style="margin-right: 50px;"></div>
</a>
```

I have the `a` tag having `class="showWifi"`.

I have to use JQuery to select the first `div` element inside this `a` tag having `class="showWifi"`.

I don't want set an `id` to this tag, but I want use the JQuery syntax to select the first `div` tag

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$('a.showWifi div').first().addClass('something')
```

You can also use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-selector

```
$('a.showWifi div:first').addClass('something')
```

Note: `first()` is faster than `:first`(Thanks to @Zeratops). See: [jQuery :first vs. .first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312761/jquery-first-vs-first/14757072#14757072)

Comment: If we go further, for performance matters, `.first()` is better (related to this SO answers on "who is faster between `:first` or ``.first()` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312761/jquery-first-vs-first/14757072#14757072).

Comment: @Zeratops Thanks, Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

> Selects the first matched element.

```
$('a.showWifi > div:first')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.first()`

```
$(".showWifi").find("div").first();
```

Working JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uamkvdkr/