# How to select the first div inside the element selected by the $(this) JQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

into a JSP page I have something like this:

```
<!-- Bottone relativo ai progetti WIFI: -->
<a title="WIFI" href="javascript: void(0)" id="showWifi_${item.index}" class="showWifi">
    <div class="news_box news_box_01 hvr-underline-from-center " style="margin-right: 50px;"></div>
</a>
```

I am pretty new in JQuery and I have the following situation:

As you can see I have the **a** tag having **id="showWifi_${item.index}"** where the **item.index** is a value generated by a more external iteration.

In this page I have this JQuery script:

```
$(".showWifi").click(function(event){

    clickedButton = this.id;      

    splitButtonId = clickedButton.split("_"); 

    idToShow = "progettiWifi_" + splitButtonId[1];
    idToHide = "progettiPnsd_" + splitButtonId[1];

    document.getElementById(idToShow).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(idToHide).style.display = 'none';

    //$(this).addClass("highLightButton");

    $('a.showWifi div').first().addClass('highLightButton');
    $('a.showPnsd div').first().removeClass('highLightButton');


});
```

The last 2 rows select the first div inside the **a** tag having **showWifi** as class. The problem is that I have to replace these lines using the first div inside the **$(this) element that represent the clicked element.

How can I do this thing?

Answer (score 3):

In case you have more than one `divs` inside `<a>`, you can use the following code to get the first div.

```
$(this).find('div').first().addClass('highLightButton');
```

Please check this solution: [How can I use JQuery to select the first div element inside a container element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498101/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-select-the-first-div-element-inside-a-container-element/32498157#32498157)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one div within `.showWifi` you do not need `first()`

```
 $(this).find('div').addClass('highLightButton');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).children('div:first').addClass('highLightButton');
$(this).children('div:first').removeClass('highLightButton');
```

More info: https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: If the div you desire is direct descendant of the clicked element, you can also use .children().