# Unexpected call to method or property access on IE8 in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have an error on my site:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 27 Jul 2012 08:54:50 UTC


Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 5855
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://garmonia-znakomstva.ru/js/jquery-1.7.2.js
```

Is this jQuery incompatible with IE8 or some my error?

Error occuring while opening http://garmonia-znakomstva.ru/

**CODE**

This is jQuery code fragment:

```
prepend: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
5855:           this.insertBefore( elem, this.firstChild );
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Links can rot (and links like that one usually do), and people shouldn't have to follow links to random websites in order to help you. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: *"Is this jQuery incompatible with IE8...?"* Of course not.

Comment: I think you might find your answer in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275702/jquery-first-child-of-this

Comment: Meh, the error points out to `.prepend`, yet there is no custom code that calls `.prepend`

Comment: Install IE9 in a VM, and switch it to compatibility mode - it has a much better debugger, however, some of the bugs are fixed in it compared to 'real' IE8. Issue could be that you want to prepend the element before itself or prepend it to itself?

Comment: I have so far nailed it to `prependTo(this.headers)` in the jQuery UI accordion code... so it's being used wrong or just a buggy plugin

Comment: @Esailija can you hint me where to look for jQuery UI accordion compatibility list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An error occurs when the jquery meets `<script>` tag inside the div#accordion.
Try to move the tag `<script>` out

Comment: I just googled and found out this as well, I didn't notice the script tag there yet, but I noticed there are multiple elements with the same ID. Should probably mention that as well, +1

Comment: +1. IE 7/8 chucks a wobbly at any code other than the <h3>+<div> structure for each tab in the accordion. Any tag outside those two and it will break the accordion.