# How can i get the li-first child of this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <ul id="playlist">
        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center grid-list" id="grid-list">
            <div>
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="grid-img">
            </div>
                <li><?php the_title();?></li>
        </div>
       <ul>
```

i used this code to get the initial info

```
initList($('#playlist li:first-child'));
```

but since the client decided to make it grid list
i dont know how to revised it when it is inside a div

Comment: Invalid Markup. `ul > div > li`.

Comment: Not related to question. Just for info .Dont make div as direct child of <ul>. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery first child of "this"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275702/jquery-first-child-of-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `li` is not the first child of `#playlist`. You want `:first` instead.

Comment: oh thanks i thought it was its child so i just omit it hte the child instead thaks for the help

Comment: It is a child, it's just not the first child. The ```:first-child``` selector only matches for the first child of any element. The jQuery ```:first``` selector acts more like ```:first-of-type``` from the css spec.

Comment: if thats the case then this would not work anymore 
var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();

Comment: That would get whatever element is the next sibling of ```li.active```. That would work just fine if that's what you're trying to do.