# Cannot add class to element children

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to find an element in my HTML file based on its parent class name and then add a class to it. I've tried the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275718/9322402) but it won't work. also, I've tried to log the child class name to see if it's working but it will return `undefined`. My HTML file is something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log($(".grid-container").find(">:first-child").className);
  $(".grid-container").find(">:first-child").toggleClass("search-controller");
});
```

```css
.search-controller {
    height: 100%;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ui-view="" class="grid-container ng-scope" style="">
  <div ng-controller="citySearchController" ng-init="initialize()" class="ng-scope">
    This is test data
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the class name from jQuery object you have to use `prop()`. Try to set some style to the element so that the changes are visible (like `color`):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log($(".grid-container").find(">:first-child").prop('class'));
  $(".grid-container").find(">:first-child").toggleClass("search-controller");
});
```

```css
.search-controller {
  height: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ui-view="" class="grid-container ng-scope" style="">
  <div ng-controller="citySearchController" ng-init="initialize()" class="ng-scope">
    This is test data
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so here it's working, but when I try this in my code I got no change, I'm guessing it's because of kendo grid and its contents loading after document.ready?

Comment: @amirdaraee, can you check the length like `$(".grid-container").find(">:first-child").length` just before toggling.....

Comment: kendo generate the code see in F12 how it looks after run

Comment: @Mamun I got 0 for length.

Comment: @Mamun tnx, so is there a way to run the code after kendo generated the content?

Comment: Write a `dataBound` event handler to run code after kendo generates the grid content

Answer (score 0):

Use `addClass` instead of `toggleClass`.`toggleClass` class will require an event like `click` to toggle the class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log($(".grid-container").find(">:first-child").className);
  $(".grid-container").find(">:first-child").addClass("search-controller");

});
```

```css
.search-controller {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ui-view="" class="grid-container ng-scope" style="">
  <div ng-controller="citySearchController" ng-init="initialize()" class="ng-scope">Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx for the tip, but it seems there is another problem, kendo generates its content after document.ready.